# Background process to present notifications when main app isn't running

Tags: android, background-process

I'm implementing an background process that will update information my app uses.
I only want this process to update say once a day, if the process gets data newer than what it had before I want to present the user with a notification, exactly like twitter/gmail does.

I want the update process to run automatically, even when the main app is not open.

Is a `Service` the best way to go? I've been reading quite a bit about this, I figured a service running all the time for something that is only going to do work once a day seems a little overkill.

However I notice google run service for friendlocation and google+ services continuously on my nexus.

I've look into starting my service via the AlarmManager so its only started when required.
Some posts also suggest using the `Handler` class, I don't think this will work.

Just looking for the best practice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I figured a service running all the time for something that is only going to do work once a day seems a little overkill.

Absolutely.

> I've look into starting my service via the AlarmManager so its only started when required.

This is the correct answer.

If you only want your code to be invoked if the device is on, implement an `IntentService`, do your work in its `onHandleIntent()`, and have `AlarmManager` start up the service on your desired schedule.

If you want your code to force the phone to wake up, you can do that, but you will need to use a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm, and you will probably want to look at my [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), designed to handle this pattern.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like I was on the right lines, thanks for decent clarification.